# getting location and running a function on a new window (following window.open) and not the old

Tags: angularjs, parsing, window.open

I'm a junior dev' and trying to open a new window following ng-click on a button, then run a function with setTimeout on the new window in order to parse a parameter from the new window url. This is my code, but it doesn't really work on the new window (nor console.log or alert):

```
 window.open("https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize?client_id=499eec7e74084561ac8cd8018fd090f2&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&response_type=code")
        setTimeout(function(){
            var wl = window.location
            alert(wl);
            wl = wl.href.split("/code")
            console.log("this is wl", wl);
            wl = wl[1]
            carrotService.connectRunkeeper(wl)
        }, 5000)
```

Appreciate your time and help,

Ark

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a proper actionable problem statement. Why are you trying to split on `"/code"` when those characters don't exist together? What are you trying to pass to the function? This would be a good time to review [ask]

Comment: I think you need to attach `window.open` to a variable and use that. So `var opener = window.open(...`

Answer (score 0):

Since you can easily call functions on a popup window's opener why not have your new window call a function on the opener once it resolves to your redirect URI

On the page it redirects to (defined as redirect_uri in your location string), you could have some on-load JS code that gets the parameter you need and sends it to the window.opener

ie:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var val=getQueryVariable(PARAM_YOU_NEED)
    window.opener.myFunctionOnWindowLoad(val)
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
```

(Borrowed that non-jQuery param code from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Would that fix your wagon or did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply John! It didn't really help me, but I think it's me, not your advice. Meanwhile I was trying to do the following: add a route in the app.js to get the auth_code from the url, then send it to the services and from there to the server, but I keep getting 400